# An error occurs when trying to push an object into a mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, events, mongoose

I'm using mongoose(5.0.1) for MongoDB operations on nodejs and an error occurs while trying to push an object into a MongoDB array. Here's the code:

```
 //quesObj and testTitle are sent from clientside
 // quesObj is just an ordinary javascript object

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('save question', function(quesObj, testTitle){   
        eventEmitter.emit('save question db', quesObj, testTitle);
      });
  });

  eventEmitter.on('save question db', function(quesObj, testTitle){
    testModel.findOne({'title': testTitle}, function(err, foundQues){
      foundQues.questions.push(quesObj)
      foundQues.save();
    });  
 });
```

Here's the error that occurs on the push operation line:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event      

TypeError: this._schema.caster.applySetters is not a function
at Array._cast (/home/mintx/testmate/testmate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:122:32)
at Array._mapCast (/home/mintx/testmate/testmate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:296:17)
at Arguments.map (<anonymous>)
at Array.push (/home/mintx/testmate/testmate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:310:25)
at /home/mintx/testmate/testmate/app.js:54:25
at model.Query.<anonymous> (/home/mintx/testmate/testmate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3913:16)
at /home/mintx/testmate/testmate/node_modules/kareem/index.js:297:21
at /home/mintx/testmate/testmate/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
```

This is the 'questions' array from the model I'm trying to push an object into:

```
const testSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
numberOfQuestions: Number,
questions: [Object]
});
```

Comment: for one, i think you're missing the semi colon on foundQues.questions.push(quesObj) . although might not be the main issue

Comment: Have you tried making that an Array instead of an object inside of your schema for questions.  you are trying to do an array operation on an object and thus the not a function answer.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a schema for `questions` property in `testSchema`

You shouldn't keep simply as Object `questions: [Object]`

**To fix your code you need to**

1.Create a `questionSchema` in whatever structure you wish, below is a sample structure of `questionSchema`

```
const questionsSchema =  new Schema({
    topic : {
        type : String
    }
});
```

2.Add the `questionSchema` to `questions` property in `testSchema`

```
const testSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    numberOfQuestions: Number,
    questions: [questionSchema]
});
```

3.After adding a schema to `questions` property ***(as per the above example the schema you have to add is `questionSchema`)*** `foundQues.questions.push(quesObj)` will work